# Can anyone please explain this piece of code?

Tags: javascript, regex, do-loops

```
do{    
         var string1=prompt("Enter text");     
} while(!string1||!/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(string1));
```

Can someone please explain to me the condition inside while in detail?

Comment: what do you now understand? How a do while works or what is a regular expression?

Comment: I know how a do while works, I need to know what exactly regular expression does.

Comment: It is a pretty basic regular expression. Visualize it with [regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5Cs%5D*%24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!string` will be true if the string is not empty, meaning
`string !== '' && string !== null && string !== false && string !== undefined`

The regular expression `/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/` matches any string that only contains a letter/whitespace and by doing `!` we want the oppossite. A string that contains at least one character that it is not a letter/whitespace

[image]

The `.test` method evaluates a regular expression against a given string, and will return `true` if the pattern matches the string.

So:

```
'333' // true
' 333' // true
'aaa' // false
'   ' // false
'3a3' // true
```

```js
const arr = [
  '333', // I have at least 1 non letter/whitespace
  '444', // I have at least 1 non letter/whitespace
  ' 44', // I have at least 1 non letter/whitespace
  'a$', // I have at least 1 non letter/whitespace
  'aaaa', // false
  'ZZZ', // false
  '   ', // false
  '"$a%' // I have at least 1 non letter/whitespace
];

arr.forEach(string => {
  console.log(`${string}: ${!/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(string)}`);
});
```